# How to structure document with multiple image toggles

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently I am coding a non-profit website which gives information about the background of meat consumption and its consequences for the climatic change etc.

Its an infographic which will be animated in a very simple "click and see information" way.

[image: before]
[image: after]

So the elements with a white border are clickable, and by clicking I replace the image with another and add text to different spots.

**My Problem**:

The images with "text 1/2" overlap, when I have clicked both images. I want the currently displayed image do disappear as soon as the other overlapping image is activated.

This issue appears more than once. For example text 1 overlaps with text 2 and text 3 overlaps with text 4. Hiding/Showing text 1/2 should not influence hiding/showing text 3/4

This is a one time process. I cannot click elements twice!

[You can see an minimized example of my problem here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8ja892cv/1/)

I am looking for a smart solution and would love to receive some hints/tips you have got!

`best regards`

Comment: Sounds like a pretty straightforward issue, although I still have problem understanding your requirements. Perhaps [creating a **MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help tremendously.

Comment: Instead of describing the problem in length and giving an example that does not demonstrate the problem, create an example replicating the problem you have on fiddle or as snippet so we can work on it.

Comment: @terry it was quite hard to try to explain this, so I can understand this. I have tried to create a minimized version of this problem. Hope now its easier to understand!

Comment: If you don't want 1/2 to affect 3/4, then you need to group like elements in a shared container of sorts. Your HTML needs adjustment for this to work, or you're gonna end up writing overly complicated selector tags in jQuery.

Comment: Wrapping an container around the two items of course is very simple and effective! I haven't thought about that. Thanks for this hint! If you update your answer I would love to check it as correct one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a class to your pop-ups and then hide the class before doing anything else:

HTML...

```
<img class="hide" height="200" width="200" alt="text 1 overlaps" />
```

jQuery...

```
$(".box img:first-child").click(function(){

    $('.hide').hide();

    $(this).parent().find("img").toggle();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is a quite simple solution and would work fine, if theres just the two images. The problem is, that there are several texts overlapping each other, and all the other texts should be displayed nevertheless.

Comment: Could you update your fiddle to use more than 2 images then? Also, your comment is kinda confusing. I get the problem being overlapping texts, but then you say they should be displayed regardless of anything....huh?

Comment: Yeah, its kind a hard to talk about it. I have updated my jsfiddle and explanation. I hope this makes it more clear!